# What is the purpose of the load File.Join line in config.rb for Sencha Touch?

Tags: ruby, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sass, compass-sass

The config.rb used in the theming demo looks like so:

```
# Get the directory that this configuration file exists in
dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)

# Load the sencha-touch framework
load File.join(dir, '..', 'touch', 'resources', 'themes')

# Look for any *.scss files in same directory as this file
# Place compiled *.css files in the parent directory
sass_path    = dir
css_path     = File.join(dir, "..")
output_style = :expanded
environment  = :development
```

What is the purpose of the File.join line?  It appears to be an incorrect path in relation to the theming demo that I have downloaded from github:

https://github.com/senchalearn/Touch-Theming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the `Ruby` docs:

Returns a new string formed by joining the strings using File::SEPARATOR.

Here is a link to the docs:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html

Basically, `File.join` joins the strings together, returning a new string used in a file path.